# Given $Var(X)=8100,Var(Y)=10000,Var(X+Y)=20000$, calculate $Var(X+500+(1.08)Y)$.

Tags: probability, self-learning

> In considering medical insurance for a certain operation, let $X$ equal the amount (in dollars) paid for the doctor and let $Y$ equal the amount paid to the hospital. In the past, the variances have been $Var(X)=8100,Var(Y)=10000,Var(X+Y)=20000$. Due to increased expenses, it was decided to increase the doctor's fee by \$500 and increase the hospital charge $Y$ by 8%. Calculate the variance of $X+500+(1.08)Y$, the new total claim.

Assuming independence of $X$ and $Y$ we know that in the past: 
$$Var(X+Y)=a^2(8100)+b^2(10000)=20000$$
Without more information I am unsure how to solve for $a$ and $b$ and proceed with the next calculation.

Comment: If you are wanting to solve $$Var(X+500+1.08Y)$$ do you need to solve $$Var(X+Y)$$ Since you already know Var(X) and Var(y)?  Is it possible you are focusing on information you do not need? For example, can you solve as $$Var(x)+Var(c)+(1.08)^2Var(Y)$$ ?? And keep in mind that $$Var(c)=0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ were independent, then $$\operatorname{Var}[X+Y] = \operatorname{Var}[X] + \operatorname{Var}[Y],$$ but this is not possible because that would imply $20000 = 10000 + 8100$.  So right away we know that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent in some fashion:  their covariance is nonzero and the formula is $$\operatorname{Var}[aX+bY] = a^2 \operatorname{Var}[X] + b^2 \operatorname{Var}[Y] + 2ab \operatorname{Cov}[X,Y].$$  In the case that $a = b = 1$, this becomes $$ \operatorname{Var}[X+Y] = \operatorname{Var}[X] + \operatorname{Var}[Y] + 2 \operatorname{Cov}[X,Y].$$  Substituting the values for the variances we were given above allows us to obtain the covariance between $X$ and $Y$.

Now to compute the variance of $X + 500 + 1.08 Y$, we note that $$\operatorname{Var}[X+500+1.08Y] = \operatorname{Var}[X + 1.08Y]$$ since $500$ is constant.  Now since the covariance is known, we may return to the first formula with the choice $a = 1$, $b = 1.08$, $\operatorname{Var}[X] = 8100$, $\operatorname{Var}[Y] = 10000$, and $\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y] = ???$ to obtain the desired variance.

Comment: The key for me here was realizing that $a$ and $b$ were equal to $1$ as we were told there was *one* hospital expense and *one* doctor expense. Thanks for your insight.